# What is wrong with this Vhost setting?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, fedora, virtualhost, namevirtualhost

I posted a question about this issue earlier but i am pasting the vhost file [here](http://pastie.org/1512536) to show that i am going to the same location when i go to nacc.biz and kadence.tv if you look at the bottom of the file it shows that i set the NameVirtualHost but why are they going to the same location....

the files for kadence is

```
/var/www/html/
```

the files for nacc is

```
/var/www/html/nacc/
```